# How do I send data to CSV fields of respective column headers

Tags: php, csv

I'm a complete newbe to CSV files. I am trying to find out how to send data from any source, and have that data get put into its respective columns, i.e. - Address, Date, etc. Also, how do I go about making the headers in the first place. I have tried fputcsv() function, but that just seems to write to the fields. 
Is there like a CSV site?

Please Help...

Comment: Isn't http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php enough explanation? CSV is no more than a file where the values are separated  by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the headers as the first element of your array.  Let's say you have the following array:

```
$values = array(
    array(
        "123 Main St.",
        "1/1/2012"
    ),
    array(
        "456 Somewhere Ave.",
        "2/1/2013"
    )
);
```

You would then use the following to put your headers at the beginning of that array:

```
array_unshift( $values, array( "Address", "Date" ));
```

Then write the file:

```
$fp = fopen( "file.csv", "w" );

foreach( $values as $line ) {
    fputcsv( $fp, $line );
}

fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: That works however, every time I submit a form it creates a new row of headers (the same headers repeated ). I need to have one set of headers, and then have the data appended to that each time a user submits form data. P.S. I changed the "w" argument to "a+", so it appends the data.

Comment: In the CSV format, the headers are just another row, there's nothing special about them. The code above creates a brand new file each time with one set of headers. It expects `$values` at the beginning to contain the entirety of the file (without the headers, which are added by `array_unshuft()`. If you're running through it multiple times, remove the `array_unshift()` for any successive runs so that the headers aren't added again. I don't know anything about the form you're submitting that you've referred to, so I couldn't give you anything more specific than that without seeing it.